# Is it possible to restart a process in Google Cloud run

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-run

We have multiple Google Cloud Run services running for an API. There is one parent service and multiple child services. When the parent service starts it loads a schema from all the children.

Currently there isn't a way to tell the parent process to reload the schema so when a new child is deployed the parent service needs to be restarted to reload the schema.

We understand there there are 1 or more instances of Google Cloud Run running and have ideas on dealing with this, but are wondering if there is a way to restart the parent process at all. Without a way to achieve it, one or more is irrelevant for now. The only way found it by deploying the parent which seems like overkill.

The containers running in google cloud are Alpine Linux with Nodejs, running an express application/middleware. I can stop the node application running but not restart it. If I stop the service Google Cloud Run may still continue to serve traffic to that instances causing errors.

Perhaps I can stop the express service so Google Cloud run will replace that instance? Is this a possibility? Is there a graceful way to do it so it tries to complete and current requests first (not simply kill express)?

Looking for any approaches to force Google Cloud Run to restart or start new instances. Thoughts?

Comment: Do the child services run inside the same container (like in this diagram https://gist.githubusercontent.com/igponce/57e7f688ae30f7b4dcd0e54ba00185e4/raw/82cb6231a2fa2515f4408571e2231808fa751583/diagram.svg) ?

Comment: If the schema file is crucial for running the services, probably you need to include it _inside_ the container that runs the service. Maybe triggering a cloud build for them on file change, then redeploying the cloud run services.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The schema is dynamic across the children and does not belong in the container.

Comment: No, each child runs in it's own container as a separate microservice

Answer (score 2):

Your design seems, at high level, be a cache system: The parent service get the data from the child service and cache the data.

Therefore, you have all the difficulties of cache management, especially cache invalidation. There is no easy solution for that, but my recommendation will be to use memorystore where all child service publish the latest version number of their schema (at container startup for example). Then, the parent service checks (at each requests, for example) the status in memory store (single digit ms latency) if a new version is available of not. If a new, request the child service, and update the parent service schema cache.

If applicable, you can also set a TTL on your cache and reload it every minute for example.

---

**EDIT 1**

If I focus only on Cloud Run, you can in only one condition, restart your container without deploying a new version: set the max-instance param to 1, and implement an exit endpoint (simply do `os.exit()` or similar in your code)

Ok, you loose all the scale up capacity, but it's the only case where, with a special exit endpoint, you can exit the container and force Cloud Run to reload it at the next request.

If you have more than 1 instance, you won't be able to restart all the running instances but only this one which handle the "exit" request.

Therefore, the only one solution is to deploy a new revision (simply deploy, without code/config change)

Comment: I really appreciate the response! I purposely left out application details as I wanted to focus Google Cloud Run and if there is a way to reload a container, hence, restart the service. Since we devs always want details, this is a GraphQL federated API configuration. Parent is a gateway and children are sub-graph endpoints. The gateways only way to refresh the schema is through polling, which I really don't want to do in Google Cloud Run

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit. If we did have a way to restart the process or container from within the code base, to get all the instances one thought was using pub/sub which all instances would subscribe to on startup, and all could reset if message came through which instructed it to.

Comment: It could work, or not, no guaranty. Firstly because you need to create a pull subscription for each instance. Here, no problem, except the cold start and the cleanup to manage (create the pull subscription at startup, and delete it when you receive the kill signal). The problem comes from Cloud Run: there is no (or very few) CPU allocated to your idle process, and thus the pull connection can be lost at any time. And if a message is published, the message could be not processed. No warranty, but it could work

Comment: Yeah was not thinking pull subscription, polling and Cloud Run is not a good combination. I see that a push wouldn’t work as there is no unique end point per instance. Thanks, helpful comment to straighten out my thoughts.

Comment: Keep your idea in mind, it could work by the end of the year ;) And stay tuned!

Comment: it's Jan '22, I was curious if there have been any updates around this? Or perhaps a way to redeploy a Google Run container like you can do from the GCP console?

Comment: You have the always on  CPU feature that doesn't throttle the CPUwhen no request is processed. But you pay more (because you use CPU full instance up time.

Comment: I am thinking of simply running another deploy on the gateway service when a child (sub-graph) is updated. I think this will take care of ensuring all gateway running instances are reloaded

Comment: It's 2023 and doesn't look like we have an update but maybe this is helpful?
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/trigger-with-events

Answer (score -3):

If it's a Flask app, you can use bellow code,

```
os._exit(0)
```

To exit the application, the cloud run will restart your service.

Comment: A. The question covers node. B. per guillaume, that solution, to work properly (clean up all running instances), requires max-instance of 1, basically removing scale-out.